# Startar site no IIS está retornando erro 500

Tags: asp.net, iis, deploy

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tentando aprender a configurar um site no IIS, ao digita o URL do site, esse dá o seguinte erro:

> Erro do Servidor
>
> 500 - Erro de servidor interno. Existe um problema com o recurso que
>   você está procurando e ele não pode ser exibido.

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar ocorrendo. Eu chamo o site pelo IP: 192.168.0.103 a partir do meu note book e o IIS está no meu Desktop em outro compartimento da casa. A rede é wireless, com somente dois pontos. Note e Desk.

Meu `web.config` está do na configuração padrão, sem modificações.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Teste_Javascript-20150527041121.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Teste_Javascript-20150527041121;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Veja o que eu alterei no IIS para resolver o problema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao selecionar a opção na combo seção para o desbloqueio, já dá esse erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só com estas informações só dá para chutar soluções.

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o arquivo `web.config` nela, por favor?

Comment: Esse link resolveu meu problema  era apenas instalar mais recursos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821187/how-to-solve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-remove-name-extensio

Comment: Resolvi meu problema por esta resposta: [Clique Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821187/how-to-solve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-remove-name-extensio)

Answer (score 12):

O erro real que você está recebendo, conforme seu screenshot é:

> Esta seção de configuração não pode ser usada nesse caminho. Isso ocorre quando a seção está bloqueada em um nível pai. O Bloqueio é por padrão (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), ou é definido explicitamente por uma marca de local com overrideMode="Deny" ou o allowOverride="false" herdado.

Esse erro está acontecendo pois o `web.config` da sua aplicação, localizado em `c:\Inetglobal\Site\web.config` está tentando sobrepor as configurações de módulos (`system.WebServer\modules`) do IIS, a qual está bloqueada para edição em arquivos .config de níveis inferiores. Para contornar o erro, faça o seguinte:

- Abra o Gerenciador do IIS
- Na treeview do lado esquerdo, clique no servidor (geralmente o nome do seu computador)
- No painel principal, clique em **Editor de Configurações** (Configuration Editor)
- No combo de **Seções** (Sections), selecione a seção que está dando erro (*system.webServer/modules*)
- No painel do lado direito (Ações ou Actions), clique em **Desbloquear Atributo** (Unlock Attribute)
- Se der erro em outra seção repita os dois últimos passos para ela
- Reinicie o IIS

Comment: Cara, fiz isso e continua o erro. Vou editar a pergunta e postar o que eu fiz.

Comment: Marcus Vinicius, Obrigada pela ótima explicação! estava com o mesmo problema e resolvi rapidinho.

Comment: Engraçado que a resposta ajuda mas mesmo assim estou negativo, garanto que a solução já resolveu o problema de algumas pessoas...

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso que você disse, quando clico em system.webServer/modules ele me informa o erro, e não habilita nada para colocar no painel do lado direito.